# Parameters ROS2 convention: dots or slashes

Tags: ros, ros2, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I was wondering what the official or the conventional delimiter is for parameters in ROS2:

1. dots like in namespace.param.subparam
2. slashes like in namespace/param/subparam

This test node in rclcpp seem to suggest that it is slashes: https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/b953bdddf8de213b4a051ecf2d668dad65ff9f89/rclcpp/test/rclcpp/test_node.cpp

But when override flags are used, the parameters are shown with dot delimiters.
Also this issue seem to suggest that dot delimiters are the way to go: https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/issues/286

So does anybody know what the (upcoming) right way of describing ROS2 parameters are? Dots or slashes?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404895/parameters-ros2-convention:-dots-or-slashes/) by [kimmcg](https://answers.ros.org/users/89237/kimmcg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2022-08-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-08-10**:
Wouldn't `/` be *slashes* instead of dashes?

**Comment by [kimmcg](https://answers.ros.org/users/89237/kimmcg/) on 2022-08-10**:
you are absolutely right... so stupid of me. I've edited my original question. Thanks for notifying me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These links:

- https://design.ros2.org/articles/ros_parameters.html

> Address all parameters without
> ambiguity in the names
>
> For example, one of the challenges of
> the current system is that there is a
> naming ambiguity between nodes and
> parameters `/foo/bar/baz` could be a
> node `/foo/bar/baz` or a private
> parameter `baz` on node `/foo/bar`.

- https://docs.ros2.org/latest/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1Node.html#a5ebda51ed6fa4ce8f2cddc9f77e9674e

> `declare_parameters()` (...) Declare
> and initialize several parameters with
> the same namespace and type.
>
> For each key in the map, a parameter
> with a name of "namespace.key" will be
> set to the value in the map. The
> resulting value for each declared
> parameter will be returned.
>
> The name expansion is naive, so if you
> set the namespace to be `"foo."`, then
> the resulting parameter names will be
> like `"foo..key"`. However, if the
> namespace is an empty string, then no
> leading `'.'` will be placed before
> each key, which would have been the
> case when naively expanding
> `"namespace.key"`. This allows you to
> declare several parameters at once
> without a namespace.

suggest the first option you mentioned (`dots like in namespace.param.subparam`).

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kimmcg](https://answers.ros.org/users/89237/kimmcg/) on 2022-08-11**:
Thanks for the links! I have a strong hunch towards dots too, but the first link you send show examples in slashes still? But I do see that the first link (the design doc) was updated in 2019, so technically the second link of the automated api doc should be newer?

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-08-11**:
I understand the `/foo/bar/baz` as an example of ambiguous naming in the current system (that's it, ROS1 then). Honestly, I haven't found any "laws" prohibiting naming with `/` so it's a matter of choice for programmers...?